# implementation of human like hearing skills algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I am a musician/producer and very interested in the way humans are able to identify sounds.

I am interested in a way to have an algorithm identifying different instruments that were originally mastered as stereo or mono. 
Maybe computers would be able in future to isolate different instrument tracks and remaster them.

Questions:
Do you think if it is possible for computers to emulate human hearing skills?
Do you know if there are any projects/algorithms around that focus on this subject?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: My guess: computer can outperform humans easily, having access to much more data.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for the signal processing site, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It is hard to define what exactly do you mean by "hearing". If this is sound acquiring, well it is enough to take microphone sampling sound more often than human ear. Possibly with better resolution, gathering sounds that are beyond human hearing. If this is about identifying, any algorithm would do (like Göertzel or more sophisticated for varying sounds). But emulating human hearing is pointless at this point, as this would require emulating the whole processing of stimuli, but not all parts are known about that processing. It would also require some knowledge base.

Comment: If you want to use algorithms, you should edit your question to emphasis that algorithmic part. It would be on-topic here, but as Yuval Filmus said, the dsp might be more focused at these particular algorithms. It does not matter what you choose next, still the environment should be described. Are the sounds clean and clear? Instruments vary in pitch, frequency etc.? Are these played at once? Projects recommendations (existing open-source codes) are off-topic here. Anyway, the "remastering" is also not clear enough objective right now.